# Open different PDF files in one UIWebView based on button selected

Tags: ios7, webview, case, viewcontroller

I am using XCODE 5 and I am having trouble finding a way to do the following.
I have a few pdf files that I want to open in ONE vewcontroller (webviewcontroller) but I want them to open based on the button I select on an viewcontroller (VC) and they open in a webviewcontroller (WV).

```
    VC1 -  Button 1 when selected would open 1.pdf  = case 0 in (WV1)    
    VC1 -  Button 2 when selected would open 2.pdf  = case 1 in (WV1)     
    VC1 -  Button 3 when selected would open 3.pdf  = case 2 in (WV1)     
    VC1 -  Button 3 when selected would open 3.pdf  = case 3 in (WV1)     
    Etc.....
```

I have seen something similar using the similar code to the following but I cannot see how to use it to open the PDFs.

```
    case 0:
        controller.FileName = @"1"; //Opens 1.pdf in webview
        break;
    case 1:
        controller.FileName = @"2"; //Opens 2.pdf in webview 
        break;

    case 2:
        controller.FileName = @"3"; //Opens 3.pdf in webview 
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I have included a picture below to show what I am talking about and I do hope it helps someone show me an example of how to do this that makes sense to me. I am still fairly new to Xcode 5 and OOP so any advice or real world examples with a bit more detail included would be greatly appreciated.

Example of what I am wanting to find a way to do can be seen with the link below  since I cannot post any images yet!

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7y2fg0g9ykajioc/pdf%20case%20webview.jpg
```

**Again I am very new to Xcode 5 and OOP so please provide as much detail so that I can learn from this and be able to pass along what I have been able to learn.**

Comment: I deleted the tag XCode5 since it's not relevant. Did you add it again?

Comment: @drm1963: This question is _not_ about Xcode (the development environment), it's about _iOS development_. So please stop adding the `xcode5` tag!

Comment: I have not added it back since the XCODE tag was originally removed.

Comment: @drm1963: [You did](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21450878/revisions) :-) Edit number 3 and 5.

Comment: DarkDust: No disrespect intended or implied! -                     I have yet to see you submit anything pertinent to this question but I will say again that I have not added back the XCODE to the tags. It may have loaded during a refresh or by mistake possibly but I did not intentionally change the tags back. Now if you have something pertinent to the question to add I will gladly listen!

Answer (score 0):

Use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to go to your next ViewController. In `prepareForSegue:sender`, do:

```
    if ([segue identifier] isEqualToString:theIdentifier])
{
    YourNextViewControllerClass *nextVC = (YourNextViewControllerClass *)[segue destinationViewController];
    [nextVC setURL:theURLYouWant]; //theURLYouWant is set when you click on button
}
```

In *YourNextViewControllerClass*, you create a *property* *URL*.
You open you UIWebView with this URL.

Edit:
Since, it's quite a simple tasks, you may want to understand a few things. Here are some explanations:
`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` : That's how you go the next ViewController in the storyboard by code.
`prepareForSegue:sender:` : Before going to the next ViewController, you may want to do something, like giving data to the next ViewController. (Look for how to pass data between ViewControllers with StoryBoard for more examples).
When you click on a button, you keep in mind the URL. Easiest way: use a variable of your object, and set it. Then, call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`.

Comment: Larme:  Can you provide a bit more detail? Like I said I am a real NEWBIE to XCODE 5 as well as OOP. What your saying may be the answer I am seeking but it is still all greek to me! Man wish i could read Greek!!

Comment: Some infos were added.

Comment: Wish i could say I got it, But still makes no sense to me!?! Sorry

Comment: Well I can add the buttons and such but where would I use the example code? Like I said I am a Newbie but I do watch videos on Youtube and read as much as possible but alot of it still does not make sense to me.  I can create the project and I have watched a few videos on displaying a PDF but they all show it loading as soon as you run the app. I want to have to press a button to select wheich one I want to load. Again I do apologize for my lack of knowledge at this time but I am trying to learn. Are there any exmples out there I could look at ?

Comment: In each -(IBAction)pushAButton:(id)sender, put `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"theSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];`

Comment: Here are the .h and .m files  if you wish to view what I have came up with. I cannot find what you specified in either file?  I do not know if these will help but it is what I have so far.    https://www.dropbox.com/s/iihdx1im4483lqi/PdfViewController.h     https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6xqhwqfvyvzb9a/PdfViewController.m

Comment: Learn how to detect the button was touched. Learn how to go to the next ViewController by code. Then, learn how to pass data between two controller via a segue. Then, read my answer.

Comment: You seem to lack basics. Go read some good starting tutorial for programmation. Then come back. It's useless to want to start with complexes things. Teaching how to detect touches on a UIButton, or why use @property, use variables, and stuff would be irrelevant to this topic. You lack basis, that's a fact. Some good people explained it through tutorials. Don't feel ashamed because you don't know all. Start with the beginning.

Comment: I do appreciate your assisting me and any advice! OK Oh I thought this would be a fairly simple thing to do.Is there a good place to start learning basics from? Better than other place?  Thank you again!